# Which verb and noun/adjective to describe a person who acts different in front of people to get what they want?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

> He is ___. He will ___ to the boss if he has to, to get the position.

Basically I need to know two words here, first to define what kind of person that is using a noun or an adjective and secondly what will he tend to do.

I couldn't think of any words in English, but if it helps, I'm familiar with the phrase "ser una pelota" in Spanish. I just couldn't remember the English equivalent word of that phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. He is **a chameleon**.
2. There are many phrases (often informal) that work for the second blank in your sentence: Two that come to mind immediately:

> He will **kiss up** to the boss...
>
> He will **kiss the boss' ass** to get the position.